Fourier transform of fat Cantor set
Let $C_n$ be the set obtained in the $n$-th iteration of the construction of the Smith-Volterra Cantor set, obtained by removing at the $n$-th step $2^{n-1}$ middle intervals of amplitude $1/4^n$. Call $I_{k,n}=(a_{k,n},b_{k,n})$ the $k$-th interval at the $n$-th step and for $R>0$ consider the following
$$\Phi_R(\chi_{C_n})=\frac{1}{R}\int_{-R}^R\xi^2|\mathcal{F}\{\chi_{C_n}\}|^2(\xi)d\xi,$$
where $\mathcal{F}\{\cdot\}$ denotes the Fourier transform operator.
Computing explicitly such a quantity we obtain
$$\Phi_{R}(\chi_{C_n})=\frac{1}{4\pi^2R}\sum_{j,k=1}^{2^n}\int_{-R}^{R}\big(e^{-2\pi i\xi a_{k,n}}-e^{-2\pi i\xi b_{k,n}}\big)\big(e^{2\pi i\xi a_{j,n}}-e^{2\pi i\xi b_{j,n}}\big) d\xi.$$
Is it possible to find a sequence $R_n$ such that $R_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ for which
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Phi_{R_n}(\chi_{C_n})=C<\infty?$$
If anyone is able to answer this question I would be glad to thank them in the acknowledgements of my paper, where I would like to show this example.

Is $I_{1,1}=(0,1/4)$ and $I_{2,1}=(3/4,1)$?

@ssssnnnn Yes, it is.

That is why you answered like you did. Sorry, my bad: clearly $I_{1,1}=(0,3/8)$ and  $I_{2,1}=(5/8,1)$ since you removed 1/4 from the middle. Apologies again.
